# Exporting a Report from Exchange-Online

Tags: powershell, exchange-online

I am trying to put a script together that does a series of things...

Lookup all accounts over 40GB
Look into those accounts and report back all folders/subfolders over 1GB.

I currently build it by hand and it looks as follows.

[image]

The current script I am using is as follow.

```
# Path to the CSV file
$ExportPath = "C:\EXO\40GBFile.csv"

# Get mailboxes with total item size greater than 40GB
$Mailboxes = Get-EXOMailbox -ResultSize Unlimited | Get-EXOMailboxStatistics | Where-Object { $_.TotalItemSize.Value.ToBytes() -gt "40GB" } | Select-Object DisplayName

foreach ($Mailbox in $Mailboxes) {
    # Get detailed folder statistics for the mailbox
    $MailboxStats = Get-EXOMailboxFolderStatistics -Identity $Mailbox.DisplayName

    # Sort folders based on total size and select the top 5
    $TopFolders = $MailboxStats | Sort-Object TotalFolderSize -Descending | Select-Object -First 5

    # Create a custom object with the desired properties
    $OutputObject = [PSCustomObject]@{
        DisplayName = $Mailbox.DisplayName
        ItemCount = $Mailbox.ItemCount
        TotalItemSize = $Mailbox.TotalItemSize
        TopFolders = $TopFolders | Select-Object FolderName, ItemsInFolder, TotalFolderSize
    }

    # Output to console (optional)
    Write-Output $OutputObject

    # Export to CSV
    $OutputObject | Export-Csv -Path $ExportPath -Append -NoTypeInformation
}

Write-Host "Export complete. Results are saved to: $ExportPath"
```

Unfortunately it doesn't pick up the right data and comes through blank on all fields not the user and when showing in PowerShell it looks like the following.

[image]

I have tried a couple different approaches and most of them error or come out blank in one form or another...  This one appears to have been the closest I have come.   I do know that the above does not do size, but I could not get that to work and thought top 5 largest folders should work if all else fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line here kills your rich mailbox item with an object that has a single property, displayname.

```
$Mailboxes = Get-EXOMailbox -ResultSize Unlimited | Get-EXOMailboxStatistics | Where-Object { $_.TotalItemSize.Value.ToBytes() -gt "40GB" } | Select-Object DisplayName
```

That's what `Select-Object Displayname` is doing. Then later you try to extract $mailbox.items but that is not a valid member. I recommend you break the commands down one at a time and make sure it has the data you expect. Run the command and then look at `$mailboxes`, you'll see just displayname. Removing the `Select-Object` on the end will be a great step in the right direction.

The next issue is $Mailboxstats does not have a property `TotalFileSize` If you look at members, you'll see it's filesize.

```
$Mailboxstats | Get-Member
```

It's starting to feel like this script was written by AI. If not, where did you get the idea to sort by `TotalFileSize`? Maybe there is some incorrect documentation out there.

Finally, the next issue is something you'll need to consider and decide how to handle. The topfolders will be another set of objects, this won't export to csv properly. You'll need to determine if you want to try and store all these folders in one property and if so, how to represent that data in a single field per user.

Comment: Doug, you are partly right - I was using an AI to assist, its how I have been learning - I started with what I knew already - which was using Get-MailboxStatistics & Get-MailboxFolderStatistics - but was not able to get that to work -

Comment: For instance - Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited | Get-MailboxStatistics | Where-Object { $_.TotalItemSize -gt "50GB" } | Select-Object DisplayName, ItemCount, TotalItemSize | Sort-Object TotalItemSize -Descending - which was fine for getting the mailboxes I needed but I then needed to poll them each to excel and filter them by size and it turned into this.

Comment: I do see what you mean where I limited myself - I must have done that somewhere along the way over the past two weeks working on this.  I am starting over with $Mailboxes = Get-EXOMailbox -ResultSize Unlimited | Get-EXOMailboxStatistics | Where-Object { $_.TotalItemSize.Value.ToBytes() -gt "40GB" }

Comment: I want it to run each mailbox on the $Mailboxes list to -> Get-MailboxFolderStatistics -Identity ???????? | Select-Object FolderPath, FolderSize, ItemsInFolder, FolderType | Where-Object { $_.FolderSize -like '*GB*' } | Sort-Object -Property FolderSize -Descending   - I am having trouble finding the right Identity to use?   When running it by hand I can use their mailbox username@company.org

Comment: I was able to get it to give information with foreach ($Mailbox in $Mailboxes) {
>>     $MailboxUPN = $Mailbox.DisplayName
>>     $FolderStatistics = Get-MailboxFolderStatistics -Identity $MailboxUPN | `
>>         Select-Object FolderPath, FolderSize, ItemsInFolder, FolderType | `
>>         Where-Object { $_.FolderSize -like '*GB*' } | `
>>         Sort-Object -Property FolderSize -Descending   I am still working on trying to get it to list the username in the results before displaying the results for each user.    Thanks for your help - it lead me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up with.  I wanted to post it incase someone needed it int he future and it would not fit in a comment.  It doesn't export well, but I can copy this out of Powershell into an email and it works fine that way. Thanks @Doug Maurer for the help going in the right direction.  the  "Get-Member" was game changing for me.

```
$Mailboxes = Get-EXOMailbox -ResultSize Unlimited | Get-EXOMailboxStatistics | Where-Object { $_.TotalItemSize.Value.ToBytes() -gt "40GB" }

Write-Host "Mailboxes with Total Item Size > 40GB:"
foreach ($Mailbox in $Mailboxes) {

}
Write-Host "--------------------------------------"

foreach ($Mailbox in $Mailboxes) {
    $MailboxUPN = $Mailbox.DisplayName
    Write-Host "Mailbox: $MailboxUPN"
    Write-Host $Mailbox.TotalItemSize

    $FolderStatistics = Get-MailboxFolderStatistics -Identity $MailboxUPN | `
        Select-Object FolderPath, FolderSize, ItemsInFolder, FolderType | `
        Where-Object { $_.FolderSize -like '*GB*' } | `
        Sort-Object -Property FolderSize -Descending

    foreach ($Stat in $FolderStatistics) {
        Write-Host "$MailboxUPN - $($Stat.FolderPath), $($Stat.FolderSize), $($Stat.ItemsInFolder), $($Stat.FolderType)"
    }

    Write-Host "--------------------------------------"
```